# How do I display a WAS and NOW price on my product page?

Tags: php, magento

I've been having this problem for a while now. I use Magento with Bundle Products on this website:

http://canjicabrasil.com/bikinis/wave-brazilian-white-bikini.html

But when I apply a discount, it only shows the final price not a WAS and NOW like other sites.

What code should I use to call Prices in a way that:

1. If price is full it will display only one price
2. If Price has discount (on any of the budle items) it will display a WAS and a NOW price in the frontend of the site.

Anyone has come up with this solution?

This is the code on bundle.phtml

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="price-box-bundle">
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

without looking at the code to see how you applying discounts and generating the new discounted values, i can't give you an exact answer.

but you can keep track of the original price, then when the discount is applied, display the original value then the new discounted value.

for example.

```
$originalPrice = 200;

function getDiscount($value,$originalValue){
return ($originalValue - $value);
}

echo 'Was: ';
echo '<s>'.$originalPrice.'</s>;
echo 'Now: '.$getDiscount(50,$originalPrice);
```

Obviously you code will be different but this is a general overview.

Comment: Thanks, as you mentioned, my code for the price.phtml is much different and huge, I only posted above the code for the bundle. Can I implement this directly there?